# how to count view on a post in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to add something similar to stackoverflow in a rails blog app
like here there is a viewed column in the right bar of every question I want to add the same thing in my rails app.

Comment: have a look at impressionist gem

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way to do it is have a separate ViewCount model that is associated with your Blog entry/Question entry/or what have you and increment it every time you serve that entry.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Use [**`increment!`**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment%21) method on `@post`

```
@post.increment!(:views)
```

**Solution 2**

Make use of [**`impressionist`**](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem and you just need to add this line in the controller

It provides lot many functionalities as well, got through the documentation

```
PostsController < ApplicationController
  impressionist actions: [:show]
end
```